# bad_alloc when creating 20k array

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator, bad-alloc

I have to do some kind of project and I'm stuck. I'm getting an bad_alloc error. I checked code a lot of times, tried to google some solutions, but still nothing, that's why I'm writing here.The thing is the program runs normally, but at the task manager he memory usage raises to 2GB(that's the limit as I know) and then it crashes. The program needs to check time of allocating space and copying variables. Here's part of the code:

```
class Table
{
    int *tablica;
    int size;

public:
Table()
    {
        tablica = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }

~Table()
    {
        delete tablica;
        size = 0;
    }

int *push_back(int val)
    {
        int *temp = new int[size];
        if(size % 10 == 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                temp[i] = tablica[i];
            tablica = new int[size + 10];
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                tablica[i] = temp[i];
        }
        tablica[size] = val;
        size++;
        delete []temp;
        return tablica;
    }

void test()
    {
            LONGLONG measure[100][6];
        LARGE_INTEGER performanceCountStart, performanceCountEnd;
        int cpy_tab [20000];

        for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {   
            for(int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
                cpy_tab[i] = rand() % 10000 - 10000;

            performanceCountStart = startTimer(); 
            for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
                {
                    push_back(cpy_tab[i]);
                }
            performanceCountEnd = endTimer();
    measure[j][0] = performanceCountEnd.QuadPart - performanceCountStart.QuadPart;
            cout<<j<<"."<<measure[j][0]<<endl;

            delete []tablica;
            size = 0;

            performanceCountStart = startTimer(); 
            for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
            {
                push_back(cpy_tab[i]);
            }
            performanceCountEnd = endTimer();
    measure[j][1] = performanceCountEnd.QuadPart - performanceCountStart.QuadPart;
            cout<<j<<"."<<measure[j][1]<<endl;

            delete []tablica;
            size = 0;


            performanceCountStart = startTimer(); 
            for(int i = 0; i < 4000; i++)
            {
                push_back(cpy_tab[i]);
            }
            performanceCountEnd = endTimer();
    measure[j][2] = performanceCountEnd.QuadPart - performanceCountStart.QuadPart;
            cout<<j<<"."<<measure[j][2]<<endl;

            delete []tablica;
            size = 0;


            performanceCountStart = startTimer(); 
            for(int i = 0; i < 8000; i++)
            {
                push_back(cpy_tab[i]);
            }
            performanceCountEnd = endTimer();
    measure[j][3] = performanceCountEnd.QuadPart - performanceCountStart.QuadPart;
            cout<<j<<"."<<measure[j][3]<<endl;

            delete []tablica;
            size = 0;


            performanceCountStart = startTimer(); 
            for(int i = 0; i < 14000; i++)
            {
                push_back(cpy_tab[i]);
            }
            performanceCountEnd = endTimer();
    measure[j][4] = performanceCountEnd.QuadPart - performanceCountStart.QuadPart;
            cout<<j<<"."<<measure[j][4]<<endl;

            delete []tablica;
            size = 0;

            performanceCountStart = startTimer(); 
            for(int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
            {
                push_back(cpy_tab[i]);
            }
            performanceCountEnd = endTimer();
    measure[j][5] = performanceCountEnd.QuadPart - performanceCountStart.QuadPart;
            cout<<j<<"."<<measure[j][5]<<endl;

            delete []tablica;
            size = 0;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas of resolving this problem would be really worthy to me!

Comment: can't you provide us with a shorter example? and what is wrong with nested for loops? is it really necessary to have so much code copied & pasted again?

Comment: If you suspect a memory leak, run it through `valgrind` and see what comes out the other end. Also, please try to reduce the size of your example to the minimum compilable example which reproduces the problem. You will often find that in trying to isolate this minimum example, you have already discovered the answer.

Comment: Please debug first and narrow your question. Also using a memory leak detector like valgrind would be a good idea. Most probably you are leaking somewhere, and the consumed memory unexpectedly accumulates.

Comment: Correctly indenting the code is a first step. The second one is using `std::vector` instead of `new[]` and `delete[]`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to use valgrind or it's substitute, cause I'm using Windows not Linux and then specify what's going on. I unfortunately cannot use any vector-like class.

Answer (score 2):

You are definitely leaking, and probably fragmenting the memory when you do this:

```
    int *temp = new int[size];
    if(size % 10 == 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            temp[i] = tablica[i];
        // Should free tablica here 
        tablica = new int[size + 10];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            tablica[i] = temp[i];
    }
```

First, you allocate a temp (even if you don't need to) which is `size` elements, then you allocate a `size+10` elements array, which is not freed.

I would suggest that you use a second variable to record the capacity, and double the capacity each time you're at the capacity. That way, you don't need 2000 allocations to grow the array to 20000 elements, but 15 re-allocations (and copies).

Comment: I don't think there's a leak - the expanded array (with 10 additional elements) is tracked in the `tablica` pointer, which is deleted at various points in `test()` and (improperly) deleted in the dtor.  However, I would say that the code managing the `tablica` pointer is rather messy.

Comment: It's deleted after the loop, but not IN the loop. So in a loop of 1000 elements, 100 allocations are made, and only one delete after the loop.

Comment: You're right - I see what I missed now.

Comment: The rest of the code isn't exactly fantastic either, but the leak here is what kills the memory. The fragmentation isn't helping either.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mats Petersson. It just worked. Now I understand what to do for the future operations like this. And sorry for little bit messy code. I still need to learn a lot :)

Comment: You should mark this as the correct answer, so that others that look at the question will know that it's been answered.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show exactly how you're using the `Table` class, but you're probably corrupting the heap.

The `test()` function repeatedly pushes data onto `tablica` then does a `delete [] tablica` before doing another round of pushes.

However, when the `test()` function deletes `tablica` the last time, it doesn't set the poitner to `NULL`, and the `Table` desctuctor looks like:

```
~Table()
{
    delete tablica;
    size = 0;
}
```

So it would go ahead and delete that pointer again causing the heap to get corrupted.  Note that the `delete` operation in `~Table()` should be a `delete [] tablica;`.

Also, note that having the `tablica` pointer managed across the `push_back()`, `test()` and dtor functions makes for a messy situation.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are leaking tablica memory.
Before

```
tablica = new int[size + 10];
```

Add a line

```
delete []temp;
```

And everything would be fine.

More over in every call of push_back you are unnecessarily allocating memory in temp and deleting it. Instead allocate the memory and free inside if condition.

Comment: Umm - that would make it difficult to copy the data that's in the `temp` array over to the new `tablica` array.

Comment: @MohitJain: You do mean `delete []tablica`, as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yes Mats you are right. I took long time to type the message and by the time I submitted, I ended up giving duplicate suggestion :(

Comment: @MichaelBurr No it won't